# Should my company have an SSL on our email

Tags: tls, email

We have a new IT guy that insists we do not need an SSL on our email. Quite a few people access their email from outside our office(network) via mobiles and home computers, often from WIFI connections. Shouldn't we be encrypting our emails? We are a software company that is responsible for millions of dollars worth of data, and we frequently email each other passwords and other sensitive data.

I would love some feed back as I plan to show my boss any high rated comments. Please spare nothing.

Comment: Yes. SSL all the things, all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I personally would say that *every* mailserver *must* provide support for SSL, deploying SSL is not the only way to secure eMails; usually using some kind of end-to-end encryption is a good idea, *especially with critical data*.

### You need SSL for...

SSL can protect eavesdropping for in- and outbound mails, given that both mailservers support it. So if a customer sends you critical information from an server supporting ssl, it will be sent in plaintext unless you set up ssl as well. Thus, all information on such eMails should in my personal opinion be considered as public information, like a postcard. Your customers should be worth the effort of setting up SSL.

You also need SSL for employees accessing their mailboxes; this may additionally improve the security of mailbox passwords. Not deploying SSL there is a rather big security risk, as an attacker would only need to redirect the traffic of an employee's computer to get access to his whole mailbox.

### You don't need SSL for...

However, if you only use webmail (over SSL) or only access mailboxes from a network considered safe, emails routed internally (e.g. emails within your company) are not affected from not properly using SSL on the mailserver part.

**So, I'd highly recommend SSL for *any* setup, and additionally some end-to-end encryption (PGP or S/MIME) for critical information like passwords.**

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! We do have an internal network while in the office, but we all access our email from outside the network on a regular basis. We are also emailing each other (between our own mail server) passwords and sensitive information. Our offices are constantly being hacked and they refuse to follow the most basic security procedures. It blows my mind.